# Getting 443 Forbidden Error on my custom module

Tags: 8, routes

I am learning drupal 8 and creating my own custom module. I have a clean localhost installation and was following some tutorials online to create a very basic "hello" for my first attempt.

The issue I am running into is when I attempt to go to my routing area, I get the following error:

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /tag on this server.
```

Here is my code. Can someone tell me why this isn't working? If I followed the online tutorials right, I should have access.

*tagnbag.info.yml file:*

```
name: Tag N Bag
description: 'Create a custom grocery list.'
type: module
package: Custom
version: 1.0
core: 8.x
```

*tagnbag.routing.yml:*

```
tagnbag:
  path: '/tag'
  defaults:
    _controller: 'Drupal\tagnbag\Controller\TagBagController::welcome'
    _title: 'Hello Tag N Bag!'
    requirements:
      _permission: 'TRUE'
```

*TagBagController.php:*

```
<?php
/**
 * @file
 * Contains \Drupal\tagnbag\Controller\TagBagController.
 */

namespace Drupal\tagnbag\Controller;
use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;

class TagBagController extends ControllerBase {
    public function welcome() {
        return array(
            '#type' => 'markup',
            '#markup' => 'Content for Tag N Bag.'
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`_permission: 'TRUE'` is not a thing unless you've defined a custom permission `TRUE` (and if you did, I'd advise you to change that). What you have is looking to see if a user has the permission `TRUE` - which I doubt any user has, and correctly denying access. If you want to grant access to the route for everyone, in all contexts, use `_access: 'TRUE'`. See [Structure of Routes](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/structure-of-routes) on d.o for more info.

Comment: I removed _permissions and added _access: 'TRUE' as you recommended, but I still am getting the 443 forbidden error.

Comment: Make sure you clear cache, and also in your .yml, requirements should be indented at the same level as defaults.

Answer (score -1):

You missing `\` in `'Drupal\tagnbag\Controller\TagBagController::welcome'` change *tagnbag.routing.yml*  by:

```
tagnbag.tagnbag:
  path: '/tag'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\tagnbag\Controller\TagBagController::welcome'
    _title: 'Hello Tag N Bag!'
  requirements:
    _access: 'TRUE'
```